# C# application talking with ruby msgpack server which is expecting a ruby-type hash?

Tags: c#, ruby, msgpack

I am looking to build a small application to talk with a ruby msgpack server in C#. My only holdup so far is that the API behind the server is expecting to pull out a ruby hash. Can I use a simple dictionary/key-value pair type in C#? If not, what would you suggest?

I will be using the library mentioned on the msgpack  website (http://wiki.msgpack.org/display/MSGPACK/QuickStart+for+C+Sharp). However, it only seems to support primitive types? I have tried to go the IronRuby way, however there is a very crippling bug in mono that prevents you from using it. https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2770

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that different part of the system can be built using different technology stacks. Because these parts should be able to talk to each other (this way or another) it is important to specify *contracts* between subsystems.

It is really important to *think first* about these contracts as these parts of your system (subsystems) can be (and will be, no doubt) subjects of changes (due to evolving their business logic, bug fixes, etc.).

By having these contracts you allow subsystems to be changed independently without impacting all their "clients" (other subsystems). Otherwise you will end up with "I need to fix this, but may affect tonnes of places I even don't know about" syndrome.

Well, as soon as you hold the contract you can do whatever you want within the given subsystem, which is just a Heaven! :)

This means that instead of "pulling out the ruby hash" you normally want to define a *platform-agnostic contract* that will be exposed as an aspect **in terms of the business logic of your application**. This contract then can be consumed by any other subsystem written in any technology.

It also means that instead of just passing some *data* between subsystems you want to pass some *objects*. These objects not only contain the data you want to pass, but also *describe* this data, dive it some meaning. By this "description" I mean the object type, property names, ect. Objects are self-descriptive, you know.

You may declare the contract for your ruby subsystem saying "I accept these queries and I return these results". Both query (method) and result (object) should be formulated in terms of business logic of the specified subsystem. For example, `GetProducts` contract should probably return a list of `Product` objects, not some meaningless "ruby hashes". So all the consumers will know what the contract is and what to expect.

You can make it a standard then, saying "between subsystems all the objects passed are serialized to JSON (or XML)", which is more than trivial in Ruby, C# or any other language, as well as truly platform-agnostic.

Therefore, back to your question, you normally just have no such problem in your live as translating ruby types into .NET types using some buggy libraries, or doing similar crazy things :)

Simply defining contracts and standardizing transport (JSON?) helps you in *many* ways starting from getting rid of this problem and all the way through to having the clean and easily maintainable system.